# HTML5 webcam feed, trying to draw the image onto canvas on a timer

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw the video feed (frames) into a canvas every 250ms, but the canvas doesn't get any image data. This is what I have done so far, I can get video feed from the webcam, please advice if I'm doing anything wrong in the code below:

```
   <div>
   <video id="live" width="320" height="240" autoplay style="border:5px solid #000000">  </video>
   <canvas width="320" id="canvas" height="240" style="border:5px solid #000000"> </canvas>
   <button id="btn" onclick="start()">Start</button>
    </div>

    <script>
    var video = document.getElementById("live");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.get()[0].getContext('2d');//changed this line to "canvas.getContext('2d')".


    function start() {
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream, function() {}); 
    btn.disabled = true;
    }
    function gotStream(stream) {
    video.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }

    timer = setInterval(
        function () {
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
        }, 250);
    </script>
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm trying to analyse if the image received on the canvas are good to be streamed to a web server or something similar.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the line from

```
var ctx = canvas.get()[0].getContext('2d');
```

to

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

solved the issue. Thanks.